# JAX-WS : wsgen vs WSServlet

Tags: java, web-services, soap, jax-ws

I have one query regarding wsgen and WSServlet.

wsgen tool is used to parse an existing web service implementation class and generates JAX-WS portable artifacts for web service deployment.

Also if I am deploying my JAX-WS webservice on tomcat, I can make use of WSServletContextListener and WSServlet to deploy my webservice (I am using sun-metro implementation).

So my confusion do both are doing the same work, or one have advantage over other in some specific scenarios?

Please suggest.